# Override placeholder value in third party input

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm using a third party tag-input and there's already a placeholder value. I would like to change the value of the placeholder. How would I do that? Right now it's "Enter a tag."

```
<tag-input name="tags" [(ngModel)]='tags'></tag-input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<tag-input name="tags" [(ngModel)]='tags' placeholder='My Placeholder'></tag-input>
```

You should include what 3rd party framework you're using to help us answer, but I think I have found it: http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api
If you read the docs it specifies which attributes you can change and a description of each, the one you are looking for is placeholder.

Comment: Sorry, the one I'm using is https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips it does talk about placeholder in the documentation and it seems like you just need to put placeholder="something" to override it but it's not working sadly

Comment: Awesome! Was just going to suggest giving that a try

Answer (score 1):

Hello you just need to add ***secondaryPlaceholder*** option
for ex:

```
  <tag-input name="tags" [(ngModel)]='tags' secondaryPlaceholder="test"></tag-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

u can try using jquery :

```
$('input[name="tags"]').attr('placeholder', 'Your placeholder...');
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ngx-chip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) has two different placeholders. One is used with secondPlaceholder property and it is shown when the chip list hasn't any item selected. The other placeholder, used under placeholder property, is shown when the chip list has more than one item.

I paste a documentation fragment where this functionality is explained.

**placeholder - [?string]**
String that sets the placeholder of the input for entering new terms.

**secondaryPlaceholder - [?string]**
String that sets the placeholder of the input for entering new terms when there are 0 items entered.

Answer (score 0):

Add your placeholder with `secondaryPlaceholder`

```
import { TagInputModule } from 'ngx-chips';

    TagInputModule.withDefaults({
      tagInput: {
        placeholder: 'Add a new tag',
        secondaryPlaceholder:'Your Custom PlaceHolder Here'
      }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<tag-input
  [(ngModel)]="game_ids"
  **secondaryPlaceholder="enter game id's"**
  [modelAsStrings]="true"
  [errorMessages]="asyncErrorMessages"
  [asyncValidators]="asyncValidators"
  (onAdd)="onTagAdd($event)"
  (onRemove)="onTagRemove($event)"
  #tagsinput
></tag-input>
```

[image]